# unexpected result when i entered character instead of integer value in scanf

Tags: c

here is my code where i am facing a problem regarding datatypes in c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
int a,b;
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("%d",b);
}
```

When In Entered Any Character Instead Of Integer values It always Prints 32. Am Not Getting Why Its printing 32.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. You need to be learning C from something written by an author who knows that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that gets printed is completely arbitrary. It is a result of undefined behavior, because `b` remains unassigned.

You need to check that the user has entered a value before proceeding. `scanf` returns the number of items that it has processed, so your code should not use the value unless `scanf` has returned `1`, indicating that one item has been read successfully:

```
int b;
for (;;) { // Repeat forever
    int numRead = scanf("%d",&b);
    if (numRead == 1) {
        // We've got our number; end the loop:
        break;
    }
    printf("You did not enter a number\n");
    // Consume the data that cannot be interpreted as a number.
    // Asterisk means "discard the value":
    scanf("%*s");
}
printf("b=%d\n", b);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/l3J6Id)

Comment: arbitrary is right, UB is not, unless `int` may have trap-representations, because the value is not memory-less.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the following modification, you might get some insight:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    a = scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("%d %d",a,b);
}
```

When you type anything other than an integer, `scanf` returns `0`, meaning that none of the items in the argument list was successfully filled. That means `b` has whatever value it had before the call to `scanf`. Since `b` is never initialized, this value is undefined.

P.S. Your `main` function should return type `int`, not `void`.